# Create a histogram in Python

Tags: python, histogram

I'm trying to create a histogram in python

My fuction is the next one:

```py
        def hist_hor(diccionario):
            dict={}
            
            for e in diccionario:
                if e  in dict:
                    dict[e] += '*'
                else: 
                    dict[e]= '*'
            for i in sorted(dict):
        
                print(f'{i}: {dict[i]}')
    
    histograma_horizontal(d)
```

It is supposed to look like this:

```
a: *****
b: **********
c: ************
d: ***********
e: ***************
f: ********************
g: ***************
h: *********
i: *******
j: **
```

but with my function it looks like this:

```
a: *
b: *
c: *
d: *
e: *
f: *
g: *
h: *
i: *
j: *
```

Besides, anyone who knows to represent it in that way too ?:

```
          *        
          *        
          *        
          *        
        * * *      
        * * *      
        * * *      
    *   * * *      
    * * * * *      
  * * * * * *      
  * * * * * * *    
  * * * * * * *    
  * * * * * * * *  
  * * * * * * * *  
* * * * * * * * *  
* * * * * * * * *  
* * * * * * * * *  
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: What is diccionario? Please share it

Comment: This seems like a decent use for a `defaultdict`.

Answer (score 3):

You can complete the **first part** without creating a new dictionary (remember to use `end` to prevent a new line):

> **NOTE** - Tested in Ubuntu 20.04, using Python 3.8.

```
def hist_hor(diccionario):
    for key, value in diccionario.items():
        print(f"{key}: ", end="")
        for _ in range(value):
            print("*", end="")
        print()


diccionario = {"a": 5, "b": 10, "c": 12, "d": 11, "e": 15,
               "f": 20, "g": 15, "h": 9, "i": 7, "j": 2, }

hist_hor(diccionario)
```

**Output:**

```
a: *****
b: **********
c: ************
d: ***********
e: ***************
f: ********************
g: ***************
h: *********
i: *******
j: **
```

But if you need to create a new dictionary, use `update` instead of trying to manipulate indexes:

```
def hist_hor(diccionario):
    # Do not use dict as a variable name; it shadows a builtin type
    new_dicc = {}
    for key, value in diccionario.items():
        temp = ""
        for _ in range(value):
            temp += "*"
        new_dicc.update({key: temp})
    return new_dicc

d = hist_hor(diccionario)
for key, value in d.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

The output will be the same.

For the **second part**, get the max value first and create a reverse loop. Iterate through the values, and if the value is greater than or equal to the loop index, print an asterisk:

```
def hist_hor(diccionario):
    m = max(diccionario.values())
    for i in range(m, 0, -1):
        for x in diccionario.values():
            if x >= i:
                print("* ", end="")
            else:
                print("  ", end="")
        print()
```

**Output:**

```
          *         
          *         
          *         
          *         
          *         
        * * *       
        * * *       
        * * *       
    *   * * *       
    * * * * *       
  * * * * * *       
  * * * * * * *     
  * * * * * * *     
  * * * * * * * *   
  * * * * * * * *   
* * * * * * * * *   
* * * * * * * * *   
* * * * * * * * *   
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: There are a few ways. You can use `operator.itemgetter` and `collections.OrderedDict`, or you can flip the values and the keys:  
`new_dicc = dict(sorted((value, key) for (key, value) in new_dicc.items()))`  
The easiest way is to use `sorted` with a lambda function:  
`new_dicc = dict(sorted(new_dicc.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))`

Comment: YW @maría-josé, but please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work